# How to bind to type Window as a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm, resourcedictionary

My WPF application uses a Resource Dictionary. I'm also using MVVM.

I am binding to a ResourceDictionary, but want to bind my MainWindow ViewModel to the MainWindow (of type Window) but MVVM won't let me as MainWindow it's not type UserControl.

```
   <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource Mwvm}" />
    </Grid.DataContext>
</Grid>
```

This means I can't do this

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:MainWindowViewModel}">
    <root:MainWindow x:Key="Mwvm" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Does any one know how I can do the same thing but when the object is a Window and only using XAML (I know I can do this with code behind in the app.xaml onstartup())?

**EDIT**
To make this very clear, I know that within my MainWindow I can declare a namespace to my ViewModel, but is this the correct way when the namespace is already referenced in my ResourceDictionary and I'm referencing my ResourceDictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm how about?

```
<Window>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <someNs:YourVmClass /> <!-- calls the empty c_tor of the class-->
    </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

(I'm not sure, if I understood your question. But I guess, that's what you really want.)

**According to your edit:**

Sure you could do something like

```
<!-- Define an instance of your VM in the ResourceDictionary -->
<ResourceDictionary>
    <someNs:YourVmClass x:Key="InstOfYourVmClass" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In your view you could do something like this.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.DataContext>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="InstOfYourVmClass" />
    </Grid.DataContext>
</Grid>
```

But I would strongly recommend not to choose this approach. Problem is, everytime you're referencing this `ResourceDictionary` the current instance `InstOfYourVmClass` will be overwritten by a new instantiated version.

Comment: This is so close, but, this would involve me declaring the namespace in my MainWindow. Can I do this using the namespace declared in the ResourceDictionary instead of having it defined twice (once in my ResourceDictionary and once in my MainWindow)! My question is not clear, updating now. +1